# Best practices in handling MQTT messages with Paho Java library

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I'm developing a REST API interface that, in some parts, has to interact with MQTT through Paho client library. By design, Paho client can only one callback for every message received:

```
mqttClient = new MqttClient(MQTT_ADDRESS, MQTT_CLIENT_ID);
mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackImpl());
...
private static class MqttCallbackImpl implements MqttCallback {

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) { }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        switch(topic) {
            // Endless list of cases...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) { }
}
```

I am struggling in figuring out the "right" way to process the received message and react accordingly -- how would I write my callback by avoiding a gigantic switch() on some parts of the payload or the topic?

Comment: What is the usecase that has you subscribing to enough topics that a if/switch statement is a problem? You have to do the filtering somewhere

Comment: Don't mind about the topic: my doubts are still present when checking some informations on the payload as well

Answer (score 4):

You could avoid the if/switch statement by using a dispatch `Map`.

Define a simple interface (this is also a [functional or Single Abstract Method interface](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1)) to handle your payloads

```
interface MqttMessageProcessor {
    void processMessage(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception;
}
```

Then implement different concrete classes based on your requirements and map each topic to the appropriate instance. When a message arrives, it gets dispatched to the correct handler.

```
Map<String,MqttMessageProcessor> dispatchMap = new HashMap<>();
dispatchMap.put("topic1", new Payload1MessageProcessor());
dispatchMap.put("topic2", new Payload2MessageProcessor());


@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    dispatchMap.get(topic).processMessage(topic, message);
}
```

If you are using Java8, you can use [Map.getOrDefault](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method to easily handle the case when you want a general handler.

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    dispatchMap.getOrDefault(topic, generalMessageProcessor).processMessage(topic, message);
}
```

This is easier to maintain when new topics or payload formats are added, as you only need to add a line of code instead of digging into giant if/else waterfalls.

The same applies in case you need to dispatch messages based on some payload property. You parse the payload in `messageArrived` callback and then use a dispatch map.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Big if/switch statement is the solution.

If you have to make decisions based on the payload, you have to parse the payload not matter what. If you can filter payload types based on topics, then you simplify things by handing off payload parsing to separate methods.

Comment: Ok, so it seems my question wasn't so dumb after all... I am somewhat relieved :)

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch map seemed like a good idea to me until I found that you **can** actually have separate listeners per subscription, e.g:

```
client.subscribe(topic, new IMqttMessageListener() {

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            // do something
        }

});
```

This should help you to separate your message handlers without ugly if statements.